# How to fire an action creator once a Redux state is updated

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am building a React component that lists all the posts of the day made by users. I have two action creators and reducers:

1. `fetchUserList()` is an action creator that fetches the list of all users and is caught by reducer state `this.props.userList`
2. `fetchPosts(userId)` is an action creator that accepts the `userId` as an argument and fetches the posts published today. This is caught by reducer state `this.props.postsList`

The component looks something like this:

```
class PostList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUserList();
  }

  renderPosts = () => {
    this.props.userList.forEach(user => {
      this.props.fetchUsers(user._id);
    });
    this.setState({
      renderedPosts: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.userList.length > 0 && !this.state.renderedPosts ? this.renderPosts() : ""}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

While React tries to render this component, it complains:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

I tried using other React lifecycle methods, such as `ComponentWillUpdate()`, and calling the action from there instead of the `render()` method, to no avail.

What is the best way to approach this kind of pattern?

Comment: `this.props.fetchUserList.forEach` is this working? shouldn't be `this.props.userList.forEach`?

Comment: did you try moving to `componentWillMount()`?

Comment: @Prajwal sorry had a typo when copy pasting the code

Comment: Why not get rid of the renderedPost state and just use a pure component to render the posts? This way it only re-renders when changed.  Also try a fetchTodaysPostForUsers(userid_list) action instead so the state only gets updated once all results are available, I assume the fetch is async here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's try to understand why `React` is complaining. What your code is trying to do is to update the state when a component renders. BUT updating the state causes a re-render. So you risk to fall into an endless loop:

`render -> update state -> render -> update state -> ...`

For this reason `setState` should never be called during rendering. Let's try to see how we can make this work. We want to first fetch the users and then, for each one of them, fetch the posts published today by that user. As you are using an `async` action with `redux-thunk` you could theoretically concatenate these calls like you would do with any Promise. You can find several examples in the docs. Let's have some fun:

```
// In your action creators
function fetchUserList() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetch('http://my-api/user-list').then(
      userList => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_USER_LIST',
          userList: userList,
        });
        return Promise.resolve(userList);
      }
    );
  };
}

function fetchPosts(userId) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetch(`http://my-api/users/${userId}/posts`).then(
      posts => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_USER_POSTS',
          userId: userId,
          posts: posts,
        });
        return Promise.resolve(posts);
      }
    );
  };
}

// Now in your component
class PostList extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchUserList, fetchPosts } = this.props;

    fetchUserList()
      .then(users => {
        const postsRequests = users.map(user => fetchPosts(user.id));

        return Promise.all(postsRequests);
      })
      .then(() => this.setState({ renderedPosts: true }));
  }

  renderPost(post) {
    // You can add more complete render logic here
    return <p>{post}</p>;
  }

  render() {
    const { postsList, userList } = this.props;
    const { renderedPosts } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {userList.length > 0 && !renderedPosts
           ? postsList.map(post => renderPost(post))
           : ""
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
```

There are several ways to achieve this, looking at the docs [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk#composition) should be illuminating! It shows several way of combining and composing smaller functions to build your own flow. Instead of chaining this from within the `componentDidMount` we could have had a dedicated action creator that does that for us. I hope this gives you a better understanding of the power you have with these libraries and middlewares. My code snippet is just a simple example that makes some assumptions about your code/actions and skips all the "pending" and "error" states.

I recommend against using `componentWillMount` as it will be deprecated in the future for good reasons (see [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) and [this blogpost](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes)).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I will need to spend some time to study it further. I am currently using the async/await syntax - I assume I can still use it to concatenate calls like in your example.

Comment: Sure no problem, it is worth it to spend sometime trying to fully grasp these patterns as you will use them a lot. Translating this to async/await syntax should be pretty easy. Let me know how that goes ;)

Comment: I am struggling to replicate this with async/await syntax - do you have some code that you can share with me?